# NSIS powershell freezes installer

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, https, nsis

I nedd to add ssl certificate to https binding in IIS inside NSIS installer. Inside powershell command works perfectly:

```
Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq 'CN=WIN2012'} | New-Item 0.0.0.0!44334
```

But NSIS installer freezes when reach this script. I've tryed diffrent execution methods:

1) Like discribed in [article](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/PowerShell_support)

```
 ${PowerShellExec} "Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq 'CN=WIN2012'} | New-Item 0.0.0.0!44334"
```

2)

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq \"CN=WIN2012\"} | New-Item 0.0.0.0!44334"'
```

Where is the problem? Any other powershell scripts works great.

Comment: I'm assuming it is the Powershell process that freezes and NSIS is just waiting for it?

Comment: @Anders i don't know. All I see that after executing first or second powershell scripts installation freesez((

Comment: You can at least check in Task Manager and see if Powershell exits after a while?